# .deb package is downloading as folder in my ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, deb, debian

I have downloaded the desktime app from https://desktime.com/download but it is downloaded as a folder in my machine and i can't able to install it. Anyone know the reason behind this?

I tried installing via terminal with following commands

```
        wget https://desktime.com/updates/linux/install/desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb
    
        HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
        Length: 46990814 (45M) [application/vnd.debian.binary-package]
        Saving to: ‘desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb’
        
        desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb                      100%[===============================================================================================================>]  44.81M  8.44MB/s    in 6.3s    
        
        2021-04-14 10:39:38 (7.09 MB/s) - ‘desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb’ saved [46990814/46990814]
    
    
        Downloads$ ls | grep desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb 
        desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb
    
        sudo dpkg -i desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb
    
        (Reading database ... 244160 files and directories currently installed.)
        Preparing to unpack desktime-linux_5.1.30_x64.deb ...
        Unpacking desktime-linux (5.1.30-1) over (5.1.30-1) ...
        Setting up desktime-linux (5.1.30-1) ...
        Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
        Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
        Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
        Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
```

It's installing fine but when i check the version it's throwing the following error

```
desktime-linux --version

(desktime-linux:9886): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:03:10.575: cannot open display:
```

I've also tried the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Please help and feel free to add any comments

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please file a bug report with the Desktime developers.

Comment: We did but no response from them. Also in other systems it's downloading and working fine

Comment: Well, then don't pay for a subscription until they fix their bug.

Comment: "throwing the following error" where do you see an error? all I see is a -warning-. "It's installing fine" so why this post? "i can't able to install it" contradicts with your 1st stmt

Comment: FYI: on GUI session it starts normally and shows *DeskTime v5.1.30* for `desktime-linux --version`.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of error message

> `(desktime-linux:9886): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:03:10.575: cannot open display:`

produced by `desktime-linux --version` is incorrect. The application is installed, but it needs DISPLAY variable declared.

This application is designed to run on the system with graphical session. It has desktop-file named `/usr/share/applications/desktime-linux.desktop` binded to `/usr/bin/desktime-linux`. The application is Electron based, so it is GUI application.

So you have to switch to desktop environment and then run `desktime-linux` application.

Comment: Got it. I tried to install in desktop environment now it's working fine